# Weird Google Play order information

Tags: android, google-play

So, I just launched my first paid Android app and I see very weird stuff in my order management console.

For three out of five orders, the payment was declined. The other two were canceled FEW SECONDS after the purchase. I realize that people may not like my app and cancel the order, but I can hardly understand how is it possible that a user may get negative impression about my app few seconds after the order. Most likely the app wasn't even fully downloaded by that time.

Does this make sense to anybody?

Comment: Misclick?  Testing to see if a stolen credit card works?  With 3 declined that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Could be. But why me :)?

Comment: When I first published my own app, I had the same thing going on. That was over a year ago, and I still have that going on. I'm guessing it's pretty normal.

Comment: Aren't you curious what this means?

Answer (score 0):

That is really interesting. Misclicks is a possibility.

Another possibility could be people automated scraping the Play store for apps. This could be for plausibly non-malicious reasons, eg an anti-virus company wanting to update their signatures. Or could be for nefarious reasons (an pirating app store trying to keep their catalog up to date.

I'd be curious to see if you can find your app on any other app stores you didn't upload to. If you do could you let me know, either a PM or comment here?

Comment: Hmm...I do see it now on a few shady web sites...So scraping seems to be a possibility.

Stolen credit cards testing seems to be the most plausibly option, though. Currently I see 3 "payment declined" orders and 3 "refunded" ones, which were refunded with few seconds after the purchase.